# Check if string contains at least one of each: lowercase letter, uppercase letter, number, and special character

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I've searched SO and Google and most examples I find don't seem to work as intended (or don't combine all of these elements). I'm trying to create a Regex expression that matches (passes) if a string contains *at least* one of the following *anywhere* in the string and fails if it is missing any of them:

- at least 8 characters in length
- uppercase character
- lowercase character
- number
- special character (including periods, underscores, etc., i.e. a whitelist approach is not preferable - allow any non-alphanumeric character)

This is what I've tried:

```
if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(txtTest.Text.Trim(), "^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?^[a-zA-Z0-9_@.-]).{8,}$"))
{
    lblMsg.Text = "Pass";
}
else
{
    lblMsg.Text = "Fail";
}
```

The problem is that this isn't working as intended. The following **Pass** when they should **Fail** (they don't have special characters):

- 123cowboY
- MonkeyCow123

It seems to work fine for detecting all but special characters. What did I do wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change `(?=.*?^[a-zA-Z0-9_@.-])` with the below one:

```
       + see here
(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z0-9_@.-])
                 ^^ i kept the dot, hyphen, etc as you used, if you don't need, remove.
```

In this regex, the `^` inside the character class `[]` is negating the characters. You were almost there, just unfortunately you have placed that outside the `[]`

Answer (score 1):

While there are many ways to skin this cat, I prefer to wrap such code into reusable extension methods that make it trivial to do going forward.  When using extension methods, you can also avoid RegEx as it is slower than a direct character check.  I like using the extensions in the Extensions.cs NuGet package.  It makes this check as simple as:

1. Add the https://www.nuget.org/packages/Extensions.cs package to your project.
2. Add "`using Extensions;`" to the top of your code.
3. `"Smith23@".IsStrong()` will return True whereas `"Smith23".IsStrong()` will return False.
4. Every other check in the rest of the code is simply `MyString.IsStrong()`.  By default `.IsStrong()` validates that all 4 components are used in the strong string, but if you wanted to use just 3 of the 4, you could do so like this `MyString.IsStrong(3)`.

Your example code would become as simple as:

```
using Extensions;

//if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(txtTest.Text.Trim(), "^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?^[a-zA-Z0-9_@.-]).{8,}$"))
if (txtTest.Text.Trim().IsStrong())
{
    lblMsg.Text = "Pass";
}
else
{
    lblMsg.Text = "Fail";
}
```